# EntityFramework throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC service that uses EntityFramework. The service is working correctly and almost all queries to the database are successful. However, several times a day a query on the database throws a NullReferenceException. This is the stacktrace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Max[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
...
```

The Max() call is made from our own code.

We have no special code for creating the database connection, other than a class that derives from DbContext, which is used as a singleton:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   /// Singleton instance
   private static MyContext _instance;

   /// Static constructor
   static MyContext()
   {
      Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>( null );
   }

   /// Singleton constructor.
   private MyContext() : base( "Name=MyContext" )
   {
   }

   /// Singleton Instance Property
   public static MyContext Instance
   {
      get
      {
         if( null == _instance ) {
           _instance = new MyContext();
         }
         return _instance;
      }
   }

   ...
}
```

I've found a similar question on StackOverflow: [entity framework error - simultaneous db reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985564/entity-framework-error-simultaneous-db-reads), but unfortunately that question is unanswered.

Comment: Is it possible that the IQueryable that the Max() call is applied to can on occasion be an empty (but not null) set? Because that would cause EF to throw a fit, as the maximum value of an empty set is not definable.

Comment: The dataset is quite static, and when I repeat the failing query now, it succeeds. So I don't think the result set where Max is applied to is empty. Also, when I deliberately perform a Max query on an empty result set, I get a different error.

Comment: Singleton context.. Not good!!!

Comment: You never, ever ever ever should use a `static` or singleton DbContext instance. In MVC, you want each web request to work with a new DbContext instance. I am surprised that this is the only error you are seeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks guys, turns out the static context was indeed the root cause of my issue. It turned out to be quite easy to reproduce when we perform a stress test on our server, so that multiple threads are using the static context. This will result in the same error as described above, and also several other errors.

The context is now created per call, and the errors are gone.